# Need to run a specific feature file using the file's name (cucumber js integrated with playwright)

Tags: automation, cucumber, package.json, playwright

After successful integration of playwright with cucumber and typescript, I am able to run feature files all in one go by using command "npx cucumber-js". But I want to run a specific feature file.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-playwright",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^9.5.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.37.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

And here is my cucumber.json

```
{
  "default": {
    "paths": ["src/features/**/*.feature"],
    "require": ["src/step-definations/*.ts", "src/support/hooks.ts"],
    "requireModule": ["ts-node/register"],
    "format": ["html:cucumber-report.html"],
    "publish-quite": true
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple commands but nothing works they all run all feature files present in src, some commands I tried are

1. /node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ./features/admin.feature. (give some sort of error)
2. npx cucumber-js src/features/content-creator.feature. (runs all feature files)
3. npm run test src\features\content-creators.feature. (runs all feature files)

Seems like I am missing some thing but can't sort it out

Here is my folder structure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I found is to specify the unique file I want to run under **paths**

```
{
  "default": {
    "paths": ["src/features/YourFeatureName.feature"],
    "require": ["src/step-definations/*.ts", "src/support/hooks.ts"],
    "requireModule": ["ts-node/register"],
    "format": ["html:cucumber-report.html"],
    "publish-quite": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. this will run only the specific feature file mentioned in paths. I've found a more robust way just give this is paths
{
  "default": {
    "paths": ["src/feature/.feature"]
  }
}
Lets say I have 10 feature files and I want to run the 5th so my command would be 
"npm run test src/feature/5th.feature"
and for the 7th one 
"npm run test src/feature/7th.feature"
This makes it easy to run files in cicd also